# How to create laravel multiple joins with count and display all data

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, join, laravel-controller

In the Below Code i was using multiple table joins and i have multiple rows with the same id from the table clients_topup table while i need to count multiple rows from the table and display all data from the other two tables

in the below code i was getting only count values how to make it out

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {
            $clientsLevelOne = DB::table('clients')
            ->leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->leftjoin('clients_topup', 'clients_topup.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->select(DB::raw("SUM(topup_amount) as count"))
            ->where('clients.under_reference','=',$client->reference_id)->get();        

            $users[] = $clientsLevelOne;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you to do like this:

```
  $client_id_list =  [];
  foreach ($clients as $client) {
      $client_id_list[] => $client->id,
  }

 $clientsLevelOne = DB::table('clients')
            ->select(DB::raw("SUM({table_name}.topup_amount) as count"))
            ->leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->leftjoin('clients_topup', 'clients_topup.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->where('clients.under_reference','=',$client->reference_id)
            ->whereIn('client_id', $client_id_list)
            ->groupBy('client_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: not working it shows only the count values not all the other columns from the table

Comment: you have to add the name of the column you want to get in select().

Comment: i want get all the fields from clients table and clients_payment_type table can you add some examples @ LuongPs